# Importing shape file into R, multiple instances of polygons - how do I remove or simplify multiple polygons?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a shapefile in R. It's a map of Switzerland, and I want to label and colour the cantons (like states). I want to plot with ggplot2. However, when I import, I end up with many many polygons, when I only really want 26 polygons (ok, their borders are odd in places). However, I end up with over 13,000 polygons. When I label them, I end up with 13,000 labels, when I only want 26. How can I simplify my polygons and labels?

This is my code.

Thanks

````
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)


require(rgdal)
require(ggplot2)
require(maptools)

cantons <- readOGR("Kantone.shp", stringsAsFactors = F)

cantons@data$id <- rownames(cantons@data)
cantons@data   <- join(cantons@data, data, by="Name")
cantonsdf     <- fortify(cantons)
cantonsdf     <- join(cantonsdf,cantons@data, by="id")

cantonmap <- ggplot(cantonsdf, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), colour = "grey50", fill = NA) + coord_quickmap()

cantonmap + theme_void() + geom_text(aes(x = long, y = lat, label = cantonsdf$Name))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of your data would be helpful, but here is a way to aggregate your polygons and labels using the `sf` package and the tidyverse that should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

cantons <- st_read('Kantone.shp')

cantons %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf() +
    geom_sf_label(aes(label = Name))
```

`summarise_all` is the `dplyr` equivalent of the base `aggregate` function. It works in this case because when you perform the aggregation on the data portion of the sf object, it combines all of the geometries according to the `group_by` argument into a single multipolygon, but does not perform the `mean` function on the geometries, just on the rest of the data. Any polygons which overlap or touch within that aggregated multipolygon automatically have their interior boundaries dissolved. You can check this with the following:

```r
geom_agg <- cantons %>%
  dplyr::select(Name) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)

aggregate(cantons, 
          list(cantons$Name), 
          FUN = mean
          do_union = TRUE)$geometry[[1]] == geom_agg$geometry[[1]]
```

This should come back as `TRUE` unless I made a typo.

If you are getting overlapping labels, increasing the map size should solve that problem. I changed my figure height and width to 7.5 inches and 10.5 inches, respectively, to fit horizontally on a sheet of A4 paper and it works out nicely.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherDudley, I'm not sure I share my code. It almost worked, but in the summarise function, I get an error message. The error message states that "Column `geometry` can't promote group 2 to list". I have tried to show my data above to explain

Comment: @user1778351 If you had a link to where the shape file came from, that would work to show your data. It's just hard to test a solution without seeing the exact data you are working with. That being said, I downloaded an administrative region map of Switzerland from [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) to test it out. I ran into the same error and it seemed that the trouble area was the Sankt Gallen canton in the GADM dataset; when I removed that canton, everything worked fine, albeit with a Sankt Gallen shaped hole in the map.

Comment: I managed to get it all working by changing the `summarise_all()` call, so give the edit a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, that's really great, now I need to understand how it works. I think I get the gist of it. Appreciate the help

Comment: @user1778351 I just edited the answer to attempt to give an explanation of how it works. You might need to get hold of the `sf` package creators or someone more knowledgeable than me if you need a better answer though.